# How can I retrieve only visible field values in Angularjs? Hidden/Removed fields persist in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

If I hide (ngHide/ngShow) or remove (ngIf, filter) a data-bound form field, the value persists in the model.

This is useful if the field is later shown/added because it keeps the value, however I need to submit only the shown/present fields.

**Example:**

*html*

```
  <input type="text" name="filter" ng-model="filterText" />

  <div ng-repeat="state in states | filter: filterText">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedStates[state.abbreviation]" ng-value="{{state.abbreviation}}">{{state.name}}
    </label>
  </div>

  <pre>{{ selectedStates | json }}</pre>
```

*javascript*

```
  $scope.selectedStates = {};

  $scope.states = [{
    "name": "Alabama",
    "abbreviation": "AL"
  }, {
    "name": "Alaska",
    "abbreviation": "AK"
  }, {
    "name": "American Samoa",
    "abbreviation": "AS"
  }];
```

**Example:** select options, then filter some out

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lir6pbJDC1FNU8ZDAabv?p=preview

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Comment: I've linked to an example?

Comment: Not good enough.  Links die, and this question must be useful to future visitors of the website. See [SSCCE.org](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: why can't you filter based on `selected` before you submit? Or disable if not sending via ajax

Comment: Added code to question

Comment: @charlietfl I could compare $scope.selectedStates to the actual form fields with jQuery, but it doesn't seem right.

I tried the [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController) but it didn't contain the field values.

Comment: why do you need jQuery?

Comment: @charlietfl jQuery because it's helpful for cross-browser DOM queries. If you have a good solution for "How can I retrieve only visible field values in Angularjs" jQuery or not, please post as an answer. I'm beginning to think i've missed something obvious :)

Comment: can loop over arrays with javascript `for` or .`angular.forEach()` ...or use javascript `filter()`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Lir6pbJDC1FNU8ZDAabv?p=preview - scope object contains true (could be selected) whether the field is present or not. I need to know the field is both selected, and not filtered out. I could run the same filter when processing the form, but that seems awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may help. You can check from here : http://jsfiddle.net/mmMZN/9/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="StateCtrl">
  <input type="text" name="filter" ng-model="filterText" />

  <div ng-repeat="state in states | filter: filterText">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedStates[state.abbreviation]" 
       ng-value="{{state.abbreviation}}">{{state.name}}
    </label>
  </div>

  <input type="button" ng-click="getSelectedStates()" value="Get Selected States" />
  <pre>{{ selectedStates }}</pre>
</div>
```

controller

```
function StateCtrl($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.selectedStates = {};

    $scope.states = [{
       "name": "Alabama",
       "abbreviation": "AL"
    }, {
       "name": "Alaska",
       "abbreviation": "AK"
    }, {
       "name": "American Samoa",
       "abbreviation": "AS"
    }];

    $scope.getSelectedStates = function(){
       $scope.selectedStates =  $filter('filter')($scope.states,$scope.filterText);    
    };
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Didn't realise I could use filter like that.
cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement a custom filter and add select/deselect update logic into it.

```
$scope.customFilter = function(text){
  return function(state){
    //if filter text is empty (equal to no filter)
    if(!text) return true;

    var isValid = false;
    angular.forEach(state, function(value, key){
      if(value.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase())!==-1){
        isValid = true; 
      }
    });
    //set the selected attribute to false if state is filtered
    if(!isValid&&$scope.selectedStates[state.abbreviation]){
      $scope.selectedStates[state.abbreviation]=false;
    }
    return isValid;
  };
}
```

And apply the filter like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <input type="text" name="filter" ng-model="filterText" />

  <div ng-repeat="state in states | filter: customFilter(filterText)">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedStates[state.abbreviation]" ng-value="{{state.abbreviation}}">{{state.name}}
    </label>
  </div>

  <pre>{{ selectedStates | json }}</pre>

</body>
```

**Example:** [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wcEuZEuamChmjMZu2ZbG?p=preview)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this but it is useful to have the values persist in case the form control is shown again.